# Can we get an 2x bigger flair that will look nice in HDPI screens?

Tags: feature-request, flair, combined-flair

It's not the most crucial thing in the world but there are more and more HDPI screens and things are looking ugly when there is a text and low quality photos combined in an image.

I understand that all of the SE icons should be updated as well to a higher quality, but my guess would be that these icons are already exist in some kind of vector format so it shouldn't be an issue.